# Assembly. Grabbing a char from string

Tags: c, assembly

I need simply to grab the first character from a string and keep its decimal value (according to ASCII: if I grab `'h'` - I want to keep `104`).

I was trying to find this and tried everything - nothing works for me.

I'm getting my pointer to the first char in string in `rdi`. Result in `rax`.
I tried this

```
movb (%rdi), %al
ret
```

`al` - byte version of `rax`. As I know, 8 bits are used to store `char`.

If in my `main.c` I first put result in the character and then output as a decimal it perfectly works.
But if I right away output result of assembly code as an integer it gives me garbage.
If I check this assembly code with `gdb`, using `i r al` before the output to see the value of `al` it gives me right answer.

More than that, if I run program multiple times, it always give me different 'garbage'.

How to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I guess you're printing a string from the address of your output variable. You have to transfer it to a temporary array and add terminator at the end.

Comment: We have no idea what _"output result of assembly code as an integer"_ means here since you haven't shown us that part.

Comment: Did you write the prototype as `int`?  Because that implies that the character value is sign extended to fill EAX, but you left garbage in the rest of RAX by only modifying AL.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that worked, thank you. Just had to clean RAX in the beginning.

Comment: Or better, use a version of MOVZX (aka in AT&T syntax, `movzbl (%rdi), %eax`)